# Intentional friend class redifinition and -fstack-protector

Tags: c++, friend, stack-smash

I have been trying testing if multiple definition of a friend class in different `.cpp` files would work. To do that I defined a main class inside `main_class.hpp` file:

```
class main_class
{
private:
    int a;
    int b;

    int gimme_a()
    {
        return a;
    }

public:
    main_class(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}

    int gimme_b()
    {
        return b;
    }

friend class main_class_friend;
};
```

Then I defined `main_class_friend` two times, firstly within `main_friend_class1.cpp` file:

```
class main_class_friend
{
    main_class c;
public:

    main_class_friend() : c(10, 10) {}

    int gimme_a()
    {
        return c.gimme_a();
    }

    int gimme_b()
    {
        return c.gimme_b();
    }
};
```

and a corresponding public test function:

```
void test1()
{
    main_class_friend ff;
    std::cout << "Gimme a: " << ff.gimme_a() << " and gimme b: " <<
        ff.gimme_b() << std::endl;
}
```

and then I defined the second `main_class_friend` within `main_friend_class2.cpp` and a corresponding public test function:

```
class main_class_friend
{
private:
    main_class ca;
    int c;
public:

    main_class_friend() : ca(9 ,9), c(11) {}

    int gimme_a()
    {
        return ca.gimme_a();
    }

    int gimme_b()
    {
        return ca.gimme_b();
    }

    int gimme_c()
    {
        return c;
    }
};


void test2()
{
    main_class_friend ff;
    std::cout << "Gimme a: " << ff.gimme_a() << " and gimme b: " << ff.gimme_b() 
        << " and gimme c: " << ff.gimme_c() << std::endl;
}
```

Finally I called `test1` and `test2` function inside main:

```
int main()
{
    test1();
    test2();
    return 0;
}
```

compiled the program (no errors from `g++`), and run it. The output was:

```
Gimme a: 9 and gimme b: 9
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What's really weird for me is that `a` and `b` were initialized by the constructor inside `main_friend_class2.cpp` and not the one from `main_friend_class1.cpp` where `test1` function is defined.

Then I found that stack smashing can be easily debugged when a program is compiled with `-fstack-protector` flag. So I compiled it once again and the output from the program was then:

```
Gimme a: 9 and gimme b: 9
Gimme a: 9 and gimme b: 9 and gimme c: 11
```

so no more stack smashing problems, but both `test1` and `test2` functions use constructor from `main_friend_class2.cpp` file.

What's going on around here? I don't get it. Why there is a stack smashing error if there is no buffer overflow, because there isn't any buffer used?

My second question is: is there a way to define multiple times `main_class_friend`, but to use them in different files to make them "private" for the file inside which the class is used?

Comment: To be honest this question sounds like "I shot myself in the leg, why the pain?"

Comment: Maybe, I just would like to know how is it possible that it works like that.

Comment: It does not work. This program clearly violates one definition rule (ODR) by having different definitions of `main_class_friend` in different translation units.